# Redirect requests with specific path to localhost or other remote address

Tags: hosts

I want to load the file `a.js` locally when loading a site (e.g. `example.com`). Normally I could just change my `/etc/hosts` to point `example.com` to `127.0.1.1` but I **don't** want to load all files just the file `a.js`. Better explained by

I want:

```
example.com/a.js ---> localhost/a.js
example.com/b.js ---> example.com/b.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this (not the fastest) is introducing a proxy pass in your server config (below shown with nginx but possible with apache or other):

1. Change your `/etc/hosts` to redirect target domain name (`example.com` in the question) to `127.0.0.1`
2. Introduce two proxy passes in your nginx config:

   i. A proxy pass for the specific file (`a.js`) to the local file.

   ii. A proxy pass for all other paths back to the remote IP of the target domain (`example.com`). This proxy pass needs to be an IP addres (can be got with `nslookup example.com`) because using the domain `example.com` will be blocked as we set the hosts in step 1.

   ```
       server {
               listen 80;
               server_name example.com;

               location /a.js {
                       # your local server
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:80/; 
                       proxy_set_header Host      $host;
                       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               }

               location / {
                       # everything else back to the IP of example.com
                       proxy_pass http://<REMOTE_IP>/; 
                       proxy_set_header Host      $host;
                       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               }
           }
   ```